# How to collapse (or clean) a given array, filtering some results in PHP for a further SQL search

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter-2

I'm quite hesitant to ask here, but today I'm quite overwhelmed about a problem I'm facing with arrays.

Before anything, I'd like to note that I'm a not a programmer nor engineer (I come from design branch and self-taught).

But today I've been stuck for hours and I can't figure out how to get out of the loop. I know it's kinda embarrassing, but I'd prefer answers of the style "Explain it like I'm five".

I'm also kinda new to MVC architecture (as well as OOP), and although I don't catch up at 100%, I've been making slow but steady progress building the site.

So when the *search form* is sent from view to the controller, the controller sends back to the model an array structured this way:

```
Array
(
    [kind_ID] => 0
    [type_ID] => 1
    [city_ID] => 0
    [address] => foo
    [number] => 
    [price] =>

    // ... and so on (more fields with blank, zero or some data)
```

The problem is, I have no idea how to rebuild, or *clean* the array to discard all elements which are left blank, or zero, (or are they null?); maintaining all non-zero values and over everything, **same indexes**, as indexes are needed for a further correct query when using db->like() function.

I've read carefully all PHP documentation, and I haven't found any function to search 'something' in an array, and unsetting it. I've tried several array functions, but can't find any that does what I want.

Going to the point:

```
// I'd like to convert this array:

Array
{
    [kind_ID] => 0
    [type_ID] => 1
    [city_ID] => 0
    [address] => foo
    [number] => 
    [price] => 25000
    ...

 // To this one

Array
{
    [type_ID] => 1
    [address] => foo
    [price] => 25000
    ...
```

I hope I've been clear enough, and of course, tell me if I should need to give it a different approach.

I've been playing with:

```
array_keys()
unset()
```

But also, I don't have much idea how to loop to the end of an array, or how to build a loop based on that.

Thanks for your time, and thumbs up if you try to give me any hint. Any help will be much appreciated!

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    if( empty($v) || !isset($v) || $v == false ){
        unset($arr[$k]);
    }
}
```

So $k is the key e.g.: "Age", and $v is the value e.g.: 24

What this is doing is checking the value of that array key to see if it's empty(empty string), not set at all or false(which is false, zero, etc) and then unsetting it.  You probably dont even need the !isset part, but I threw it in there anyway, but if it's not set, you can't unset it, just more for completion so you know it exists.

You were on the right track with unset(), you just needed a nudge ... nice work :)

Comment: Holy molly... It worked!
Ahh... so many hours figuring out with foreach putting in and out the unsets and didn't remember as $k => $v !!! 
Also, didn't know about the existence of function empty()
Many thanks!!

Comment: Youre very welcome, that's also why I threw the !isset in there - Very useful at times, especially when iterating through GET or POST variables.